# FreeBSD param.h not matching uname -r

Tags: freebsd

I've updated my kernel via the sources *AND* also updated with freebsd-update from 11.0 to 11.1 as 11.0 can no longer build ports.

Problem is ports still doesn't think it's 11.1 due to the contents of param.h

in /usr/include/sys/param.h:

```
#define __FreeBSD_version 1100122
```

Yet...

```
[root@plex ~]# uname -r
11.1-RELEASE
```

Pulling my hair out, am I supposed to update it? or link it to the real sources via symlink? where does it even get set... the problem clearly seems to be the contents of param.h

Comment: At the bottom of the first comment block of `/usr/include/sys/param.h` there should be a `$FreeBSD: ...` line, is that correct?

Comment: YUP *      @(#)param.h     8.3 (Berkeley) 4/4/95
 * $FreeBSD$
 */

Comment: How did you sync the source code? From memory, `freebsd-update` is a binary update process (current FreeBSD version only). I always use the [Updating FreeBSD from Source](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/makeworld.html) process.

Comment: from the git repo. I am currently doing makeworld, maybe that's the missing thing.. will see when it is done

Comment: Did you do `make installworld` and ran `mergemaster`?